# How can I close automatically or block modal(?) popup?

Tags: python, modal-dialog, popup, applescript, layered

[modal popup and marked blue left below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPxbE.png)

Is there any way to block modal(? - this is my understing for the box) popup automatically? I'm working on Mac, The bule color marked in left below is saying "do not open one day". I clicked check-box but it shows continuously. My searching result is such popup is called modal/layered popup - I have no idea for such technology. Please help how to block or click automatically by using Pythoin, javascript or Apple script. I'm using Keyboard maestro app so I can put such code before or after opening site which has modal(?) popup. I need to open 8-10 sites so need help.

tried to remove cookies but appear continuously. I think it's better click check-box automatically. Alternative if any is also good if can click "do not open one day" checkbox automatically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://www.hanwhalife.com/index.jsp - exemple site address. how can block modal popup or click checkbox in left below automatically by using python/javascript/apple script